# Assign [String : String]' to type '[[String : String]]'

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a search function that will return the searched user in a table view. The users data is saved in Firestore database(buddiesCollectionRef). I can successfully fetch the data from firestore hwoever when i try to assign the data fetched from firestore into an array of dictionaries that looks like this:  `private var users = [[String: String]]()`,
I get the error

> Cannot assign value of type '[String : String]' to type '[[String : String]]'

Please help.

```
func searchUsers(query: String) {
    //check is array has firebase results
    if hasFetched {
        //filter results
        filterUsers(with: query)
    } else {
        //fetch and then filter reults
        buddiesCollectionRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            guard let snap = snapshot else {
                debugPrint("Error fetching documents: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            for document in snap.documents{
                if let userInfo = document.data() as? [String: String] {
                    let name = userInfo["name"] ?? ""
                    let userId = userInfo["uid"] ?? ""
                    
                    //test
                    print("name: \(name), uid: \(userId)")
                    
                    // update users array with fetched users
                    self.hasFetched = true
                    self.users = userInfo
                    self.filterUsers(with: query)
                }
               }
    }
}
}

func filterUsers(with term: String){
    guard hasFetched else {
        return
    }
    self.spinner.dismiss()
    
    let results: [[String:String]] = self.users.filter ({
        guard let name = $0["name"]?.lowercased() else {
            return false
        }
        print(name)
        return name.hasPrefix(term.lowercased())
    })
    self.results = results
    updateUI()
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types `[[String: String]]` and `[String: String]` are not the same. Because of this, you cannot assign one to the other.

- `[String: String]`: A dictionary with `String` keys and values, i.e: `Dictionary<String, String>`.
- `[[String: String]]`: An array of dictionaries, i.e: `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>`.

Judging from the for loop you have, I assume that you want to append them? Try this:

```
self.users.append(userInfo)
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the difference now. And using self.users.append(userInfo) works perfectly now, thank you!